# What is the usage of itemId inside Update inventory REST API?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2, rest-api, cataloginventory

According to the [swagger](https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index.html#!/catalogInventoryStockRegistryV1/catalogInventoryStockRegistryV1UpdateStockItemBySkuPut), the REST API `PUT /V1/products/{productSku}/stockItems/{itemId}` is used to update the product inventory.

However, for the attribute value `itemId`, I found no differences no matter I entered which values. So, the following request URLs can update the same product without any errors **AND** return the same integer value:

```
http://<magento_url>/rest/V1/products/{productSku}/stockItems/1
http://<magento_url>/rest/V1/products/{productSku}/stockItems/{correctItemId}
http://<magento_url>/rest/V1/products/{productSku}/stockItems/999999
```

Given that the `{productSku}` is a simple product, my question is: What is the exact usage of `itemId` in the request URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see the method declaration in **StockRegistryInterface.php**

```
/**
 * @param string $productSku
 * @param \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockItemInterface $stockItem
 * @return int
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
 */
public function updateStockItemBySku($productSku, \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockItemInterface $stockItem);
```

With help of this **itemId**  magento instantiates the object of

```
 \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockItemInterface $stockItem
```

then passing this object as parameter in **updateStockItemBySku()** method.

If we provide wrong **ItemId**, the inventory will be updated it default website only. If we look at the method **updateStockItemBySku()** in **Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\StockRegistry**, the code

```
$websiteId = $stockItem->getWebsiteId() ?: null;
```

So, **itemId** make significance to define the scope of website to update inventory.

Comment: When will the **itemId** make difference on the result?

Comment: Only to define the  scope of website of the product. Please see the updated answer.